# Touchpad two fingers scrolling too fast

Tags: release-hera, touchpad

I am using elementary os Hera on a MacBook Pro 2015. I found that 2 fingers scrolling is way too fast. Is there a way to slow it down? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, just installed Hera on a Thinkpad t480s. 2-finger scrolling is super fast and the sensitivity seems reverse. When I move my fingers very quickly and then release, the scroll is very slow and does not continue scrolling after release. When I move my fingers very slowly and release, the page continues to scroll wildly after release. `imwheel` didn't help!!